# Daily List View in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I am developing a Daily list view ('Todays Support List') that displays support coverage for my company. Certain people are on-call for certain periods of time (days, or weeks)

I need to have a list that displays any events that are occuring on a particular day (today), which will show people who is on-call for that day.

The logic I have developed bases it's calculation on the begin and end date. If the begin date is later than yesterday, and before tomorrow, it shows in the list view. This works great if the appointment begins today and ends today, but if it begins last week and ends next week, it won't show up at all.

What I wish Sharepoint had built in, is the option to filter events that have [Today] anywhere between the Begin or End date.

I figured I would give it a shot from Sharepoint Designer and create a workflow (as the workflows have more options than the front-end) but I am stumped as to how to go about this. Many ideas have shot into my mind, but none of them have panned out due to ONE missing feature...

Has anyone ever tried to do anything remotely similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view for the list and set the filter so that 'begin date' is less than or equal to [Today] `And` 'end date' is greater than or equal to [Today].